# set property at init with an extension in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

How can we use `extension` to set a default value ? For example, if I create an `UILabel` in my `storyboard`, i set text value to "toto" in the `storyboard`. Now I want to create an extension to set my text value to "popo" when the label will be init in the app. 
To be more clear, I want to do that to set a default value in the whole app to my UILabel. Hope this is clear.

```
extension UILabel {
   open override func ??? { 
       self.text == "popo"
   }
}
```

Please, don't tell me to set ma value in the storyboard cause this not what i need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can a "default" value for the `text` property be provided for labels created in a Storyboard? Yes.

Is it a good idea? Probably not...

Having said that, what you could do is override `awakeFromNib` (which is called after the view is loaded from a Storyboard/Nib file):

```
extension UILabel {

    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.text = "popo"
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, why do you think this is a bad idea ?

Comment: Because if you decide at a later stage that you _do_ want some labels to retain the text set on the Storyboard, you would have to either subclass or manually re-set the text on your controllers. But that's just my opinion. It could make perfect sense in your project I guess...

Comment: I see, i never use storyboard for set a value in a label, always from my Localized string to get the correct language or from some data in my viewModel

Answer (score 1):

Don't Create `extension`

You should create subclass of `UILabel` assign it to your needed place in storyboard

```
import UIKit

class MyLabel: UILabel {


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.text = "POPO"
}
}
```

You can use this class in storyboard this way

[image]