# NSTextAttachment images are not dynamic (light/dark mode)

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, darkmode

I have an image that is dynamic for light/dark mode. If I place this image in a UIImageView, the dynamism works: when the user switches from light to dark mode and back, the image changes the version of itself that is displayed. But if I place the same image in an NSAttributedString as an NSTextAttachment and display the string in a label, the dynamism does not work: when the user switches from light to dark mode, the image does not change.

To see the problem in action, paste this code into your `viewDidLoad`:

```
    let size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
    let image1 = renderer.image {
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        $0.fill(.init(origin: .zero, size: size))
    }
    let image2 = renderer.image {
        UIColor.green.setFill()
        $0.fill(.init(origin: .zero, size: size))
    }
    let asset = UIImageAsset()
    asset.register(image1, with: .init(userInterfaceStyle: .light))
    asset.register(image2, with: .init(userInterfaceStyle: .dark))

    let iv = UIImageView(image: image1)
    iv.frame.origin = .init(x: 100, y: 100)
    self.view.addSubview(iv)

    let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Howdy ", attributes: [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor(dynamicProvider: { traits in
            switch traits.userInterfaceStyle {
            case .light: return .red
            case .dark: return .green
            default: return .red
            }
        })
    ])
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment(image: image1)
    let attachmentCharacter = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    text.append(attachmentCharacter)

    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributedText = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.frame.origin = .init(x: 100, y: 150)
    self.view.addSubview(label)
```

I have deliberately made the text font color dynamic so that you can see that in general color dynamism *does* work in an attributed string. But not in an attributed string's text attachment!

So: Is this really how iOS behaves, or am I making some mistake in the way I'm configuring the text attachment? If this is how iOS behaves, how are you working around the issue?

[Note that I cannot use an iOS 15 attachment view provider, because I have to be compatible with iOS 13 and 14. So maybe that would solve the problem, but that solution is not open to me.]

Comment: I think, it's normal behavior. I'm afraid that you need to recalculate your `NSAttributedString` on mode change with `func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)`, and instead of `NSTextAttachment(image: image1)`, use `let attachment = NSTextAttachment(image: asset.image(with: traitCollection))`.

Comment: Since `NSTextAttachment` is holding an `UIImage` and that a `UIImage` doesn't know about mode, only `asset` does, I find unfortunately that's the normal behavior.

Comment: @Larme Actually there is no need to refer to `asset` when redrawing the attributed string, because the trait collection in question is current. The issue I'm pointing to here is the irony that the image _in an image view_ is live to dark mode, and the attributed string _color_ is live to dark mode, but the image _in an attributed string_ is not live. That seems to me like a bug: it seems like Apple just forgot about it by mistake when implementing dark mode.

Comment: What I meant to say is that when you do `NSTextAttachment(image: image1)`, you don't tell the `NSTextAttachment` that `image1` is for a one mode, and what's supposed to be the second mode? As it is also in my opinion, a forgotten dev from iOS, the only way I got was to listen to `traitCollectionDidChange()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's unfortunately the normal behavior, but I considered it as a forgotten feature non-dev by Apple.

The only way I got currently, is to listen to `func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)` to detect the mode change.

Then, you can either reconstruct your `NSAttributedString`, or enumerate over it and update it when needed.

With a enumeration, ie update only what's needed, and not regenerate the whole `NSAttributedString`:

In your initial attachment creation:

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment(image: asset.image(with: traitCollection))
let attachmentCharacter = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
```

Side note:
I used `asset.image(with: traitCollection)` instead of `image1`, else when starting with dark mode, your image will be of light mode instead. So this should set the correct image.

Then, I'd update it with:

```
func switchAttachment(for attr: NSAttributedString?) -> NSAttributedString? {
    guard let attr = attr else { return nil }
    let mutable = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attr)
    mutable.enumerateAttribute(.attachment, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: mutable.length), options: []) { attachment, range, stop in
        guard let attachment = attachment as? NSTextAttachment else { return }
        guard let asset = attachment.image?.imageAsset else { return }
        attachment.image = asset.image(with: .current)
        mutable.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
    }
    return mutable
}
```

And update when:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)        
    label.attributedText = switchAttachment(for: label.attributedText)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think the idea of enumerating the attributed string for `.attachment` attributes and updating their image is the best way. I might make this an extension on UILabel as that is where all the instances occur in my real life.

Comment: Indeed, an extension on Label might be a good idea. You could also listen to `UIScreen.main.traitCollection` changes (KVO ?), and post a notification to refresh all the needed labels, and register yours labels on it. It's just an idea, not sure if it's viable in practice...

Comment: Following the idea, if labels are in Xibs/Storyboard, you could use https://stackoverflow.com/a/45302919/1801544 and register them to the notification, but I'm not a big fan of overriding `awakeFromNib` in an extension.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, here's my rewrite of Larme's suggestion. I made this an extension on UILabel:

```
extension UILabel {
    func updateAttachments() {
        guard let attributedString = attributedText else { return }
        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
        attributedString.enumerateAttribute(.attachment, in: .init(location: 0, length: attributedString.string.utf16.count), options: []) { value, range, stop in
            guard let attachment = value as? NSTextAttachment else { return }
            guard let image = attachment.image else { return }
            guard let asset = image.imageAsset else { return }
            attachment.image = asset.image(with: .current)
            mutableAttributedString.setAttributes([.attachment: attachment], range: range)
        }
        attributedText = mutableAttributedString
    }
}
```

And now, assuming I have a reference to the troublesome UILabel:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    guard let previousTraitCollection = previousTraitCollection else { return }
    if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
        label.updateAttachments()
    }
}
```

It would be really nice to inject that override into all UILabels so they could just update themselves, but unfortunately extensions don't work that way, and I can't turn all the UILabels in my app into a UILabel subclass.